# Rails 3.1.0: Run Insert Script while doing rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have created some table and I want to insert some data into the table. How shall I place my code when I commit the code and some of my peers pull the code and run rake db:migrate then on their db tables should be created along with the data?

Comment: have you heard of `rake db:seed`? http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html

Comment: i haven't till your comment !! Beginner in rails . . i think it shall help . . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [seeds](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

As it says in `db/seeds.rb` add in ruby code and then run `rake db:seed`

```
5.times do |i|
  Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
end
```